# Programmatically downloading images and uploading them using ImageField via Boto

Tags: django, boto

A did a function that would download the avatar of the user from his social network and uses it as our site avatar. Am using django 1.5 and boto with S3 storage for uploaded media..

The function I did works perfectly when running local, but for some reason when running on boto its throwing an exception. Below is the code am using

utils.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
import urllib2
import requests
from django.core.files import File
from django.core.files.temp import NamedTemporaryFile


def download_photo(url):
    """
    """
    r = requests.get(url)

    img_temp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
    img_temp.write(r.content)
    img_temp.flush()
    return File(img_temp)


def graph_fb_profile_image(fb_uid, size=48):
    url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/%s?fields=picture.height(%s).width(%s)' % (fb_uid, size, size)
    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    protocol = urllib2.build_opener()
    response = protocol.open(request)
    resp_json = json.load(response)
    avatar = resp_json.get('picture').get('data').get('url')
    return avatar
```

views.py

```
        # get user avatar from facebook
        avatar_url = graph_fb_profile_image(kwargs['response'].get('id'), 320)
        user.avatar_src.save('avatar_%s.jpg' % (user.id,), download_photo(avatar_url), save=True)
```

The stack error am getting is following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/var/www/snowflake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
   response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

 File "/var/www/snowflake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-1.11.0.55/newrelic/api/object_wrapper.py", line 216, in __call__
   self._nr_instance, args, kwargs)

 File "/var/www/snowflake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-1.11.0.55/newrelic/hooks/framework_django.py", line 475, in wrapper
   return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

 File "/var/www/snowflake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 77, in wrapped_view
   return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

 File "/var/www/snowflake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_auth/decorators.py", line 29, in wrapper
   return func(request, request.social_auth_backend, *args, **kwargs)

 File "/var/www/snowflake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_auth/views.py", line 42, in complete
   return complete_process(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)

 File "/var/www/snowflake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_auth/views.py", line 111, in complete_process
   user = auth_complete(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)

 File "/var/www/snowflake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_auth/views.py", line 196, in auth_complete
   *xargs, **xkwargs)

 File "/var/www/snowflake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_auth/backends/__init__.py", line 373, in continue_pipeline
   return authenticate(*args, **kwargs)

 File "/var/www/snowflake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 59, in authenticate
   user = backend.authenticate(**credentials)

 File "/var/www/snowflake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_auth/backends/__init__.py", line 107, in authenticate
   out = self.pipeline(pipeline, *args, **kwargs)

 File "/var/www/snowflake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_auth/backends/__init__.py", line 136, in pipeline
   result = func(*args, **out) or {}

 File "/var/www/snowflake-env/snowflake/snowflake/apps/accounts/pipeline.py", line 45, in set_user_details
   user.avatar_src.save('avatar_%s.jpg' % (user.id,), download_photo(avatar_url), save=True)

 File "/var/www/snowflake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 86, in save
   self.name = self.storage.save(name, content)

 File "/var/www/snowflake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 48, in save
   name = self._save(name, content)

 File "/var/www/snowflake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto.py", line 282, in _save
   reduced_redundancy=self.reduced_redundancy)

 File "/var/www/snowflake-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 1112, in set_contents_from_file
   raise AttributeError('fp is at EOF. Use rewind option '

AttributeError: fp is at EOF. Use rewind option or seek() to data start.
```

any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "running on boto".  Could you explain?

Comment: boto as backend storage so any uploaded files go to Amazon S3 storage directly and do not store on the server

Comment: more details on the setup are here http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found an answer, I needed to add seek(0) to my function and make it as following

```
def download_photo(url):
    """
    """
    r = requests.get(url)

    img_temp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
    img_temp.write(r.content)
    img_temp.flush()
    img_temp.seek(0)
    return File(img_temp)
```

this solved the problem for me